# Big O, Understanding when the increment is doubling

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am trying to find the Big O notation of this code below, really its the big theta, but whatever I believe its the same in this case.

```
for (i=2; i < n^2; i++){
   for (j=3; j < 4i^3; j = 2*j){
      x = i+n
   }
}
```

One, I believe that the constant in 4i^3 can be dropped. And so, the inner loop is maybe, O(i^3) => (2^k)^3 for some summation of k = 0 to k = log (i^3). I am not really sure what to do from there. And, I'm not really sure if I understand that portion correctly.

Comment: What is your take on the number of iteration of the inner loop in terms of `i`?

Comment: I am not sure. I was thinking the `i` is some representation `n` so at worst case `i = n^6`

Comment: okay so lets say the inner loop, `log i^3 base 2`  because of the reasons stated in the question. Then, um since `i=n^2 => i^3=n^6` then maybe `O(log n^6)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner loop: After k iterations we have $j = 3 \cdot 2^k$. We exit the loop if $3 \cdot 2^k \ge 4 \cdot i^3$ or $2^k \ge (4/3) \cdot i^3$ or $k \ge \log (4/3) + 3 \cdot \log i$.

So we add $\log (4/3) +3 \cdot \log i$ for $ 2 \le i \lt n^2$. An immediate upper bound is $n^2 \cdot (\log (4/3) + 6 \log n)$. The actual number of iterations is not much smaller because for most values i, $\log i \approx \log n^2$. So we have roughly $6 \cdot n^2 \cdot \log n$ iterations of the inner loop.